# What is the Messages option in the "Apps Syncing to iCloud Drive" settings?

Tags: macos, icloud, messages-in-icloud

On MacBook, what's the difference between these two settings:

- *Messages →  Settings → iMessage → Enable Messages in iCloud*
- *MacBook System Settings → Your Name → iCloud → iCloud Drive →
  Options (Next to Apps Syncing to iCloud Drive) > Messages*
  (Checkbox)?

When I turn off one of these settings in one of the above processes, it doesn't turn off the other. That means they're two separate and distinct settings, right? What is controlled by each of these two settings?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]